# Auth.js in Sveltekit, how to get sessionId?

Tags: session, sveltekit, next-auth

As per documentation, I'm able to get the session using

```js
export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async (event) => {
    return {
        session: await event.locals.getSession()
    };
};
```

However, this object only has these properties:

```js
export interface DefaultSession {
  user?: {
    name?: string | null
    email?: string | null
    image?: string | null
  }
  expires: ISODateString
}
```

Is there anyway I can get the sessionId, or should I just use the email for locating the session in the database? which sounds funny

Comment: Yes, in the `SvelteKitAuth` handle function in hook.server file you can add a `callback` property next to your providers and adapter. The callback object should return a `session` function something like this : `callbacks: { async session({ session, user }) { session.user = { id: user.id,name: user.name,email: user.email,image: user.image}; return session}}`. If you use typescript or jsdoc, you might also take a look to this [github issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6640)

Comment: check this : https://github.com/CodingGarden/listd/blob/main/src/hooks.server.ts